# get node with where clause in jersey and neo4j

Tags: java, json, neo4j, jersey, cypher

if any one can help me it will be a pleasure

i'm trying to do a remote cypher query with jersey in neo4j

```
public static URI getData(HashMap<String,String> params,String query){
    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();
    String SERVER_ROOT_URI = "http://localhost:7474/db/data/";
     String cypherUri = SERVER_ROOT_URI + "cypher/";
        try {
            jObject.put("query", query);
            jObject.put("params", params);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        WebResource resource = Client.create()
                .resource( cypherUri );
        ClientResponse response = resource.accept( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE )
                .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                .entity(jObject.toString())
                .post(ClientResponse.class);
        System.out.println( String.format( "POST to [%s], status code [%d], reponse [%s]",
                cypherUri, response.getStatus(),response.getLocation()) );

        response.close();
        return response.getLocation();
}
```

in the response the status code it's 200 so OK but the response.getLocation() is null 
i did validate json passed in parameter it's a valid json
i executed the query in cypher manually and it gives some rows.

Comment: Can you give an example of your cypher query, and what you want as a response (body & header) ? I don't really see what you want. Cheers.

Comment: this is where i make my parameters with a cypher query : public static boolean isLoginCorrect(String pseudo,String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException{ HashMap<String,String> params = new HashMap(); params.put("pseudo", pseudo); params.put("password", Security.getInstance().getMd5Key(password)); String query = " MATCH (n) WHERE n.pseudo = '"+pseudo+"' RETURN n"; if(RESTUtil.getData(params, query) != null ) return true; return false; } thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the header when you do a cypher query, all the response is in the body as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found my answer. My JSON response:

```
response.getEntity(String.class)
```